# Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I want to change the header's User-Agent to something like `{"User-Agent":"someCustomValue"}`
but I get this error:

> Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent"

How to solve this?
The problem only appears in flutter-web, it's ok in android and ios.

Comment: Flutter web are running as JavaScript in a browser. You are properly (for very good reasons...) not able to change the `User-Agent` and a few other headers in a call made from JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Need to send headers in api fetch.

fetch(url, {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
Accept: 'application/json',
},
});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).